# Setting multiple possible lengths in RegEx

Tags: regex

Say you want to match a string that begins with 38 or 39 and has a total length of either 14 or 16. Below is my best attempt at making this expression. It works if I remove the 14 for strings with 14 characters, or the 12 for strings with 16 characters.

`^(38|39)\d{12|14}$`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use optional quantifiers, but you can use optional grouping just as you did with your first part:

```
^(38|39)(\d{12}|\d{14})$
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want either 14 or two more,

```
^(38|39)\d{14}(\d{2})?
```